# Column not found exception when trying to concatenate columns in select statement

Tags: java, mysql

I have in my java code:

```
StringBuilder stringQuery = new StringBuilder("select product_id, type || '_' || price as info ");
SQLQuery q = createSQLQuery(stringQuery.toString());
 q.list();
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column '' not found.
```

Comment: || looks like Oracle string concat.  Is that also correct for mysql?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I don't believe so. || is also used in SQLite, but in my experience with MySQL I've used `CONCAT()`

Comment: Also, OP, are you missing a `from myTable` block or is that implied elsewhere in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`||`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) is an `OR` operator in MySQL, it won't concatenate the values of `type`, `'_'` and `price`. Probably you want/need to use the [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
StringBuilder stringQuery = new StringBuilder("select product_id, CONCAT(type, '_', price) as info ");
//...
```